# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 - update entites

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

In one of our projects we have integrated Microsoft Dynamics 2011 using its SDK. However, when querying `Accounts`, not all the fields get included.

The missing fields are not included in the local `CrmEntities.cs`, which apparently has been generated by some tool. However, I don't understand how to re-generate the file (I have not been working with CRM before).

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

The tool was probably CrmSvcUtil which allows you to generate early bound classes. You need to regenerate the early bound classes when your entity model changes.

See [Create early bound entity classes with the code generation tool (CrmSvcUtil.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844(v=crm.5).aspx)

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:http://<serverName>/<organizationName>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
    /out:<outputFilename>.cs /username:<username> /password:<password> /domain:<domainName>
    /namespace:<outputNamespace> /serviceContextName:<serviceContextName>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be generated using [Early Bound Generator](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/DLaB.Xrm.EarlyBoundGenerator/) from XrmToolbox.

Even you can do the same from `CrmSvcUtil` from SDK, manually in command mode.